# how i can show two different fields from two different table on one fileld in Odoo 9?

Tags: python, odoo-9

This is a tricky question !!

My example "mail" : I have two type of mail .. **"Incoming mail"** and **"Issued Mail"** ,so I create two Table and worked perfectly.. 
now I wanna to create a third Table name it "General mail" Which includes the Group of fields from **"Incoming mail"** and **"Issued Mail"** ...
My code is:

**Incoming mail**

```
class IncomingMail(audit.MailModel):
    _name = 'incoming.mail'
    _inherits = _inherits = {'general.mail.adm': 'mail_id'}

    name = fields.Char(string="Number Mail",
                       help="contient code courr", readonly=True,
                       requred=True, index=True,
                       )
    senders = fields.Char(string="The Senders", required=True,
                          help="contains name of mail senders")
    reception_date = fields.Date(string="Reception Date",
                        help="contains date arrival of incoming mail")
    mail_subject = fields.Char(string="Mail Subject",
                               help="contains the subject of messaging")

    doc_ref = fields.Char(string="Document Reference",
                          help="contains Reference doc")
    doc_date = fields.Date(string="Document Date",
                           help="contains date of Document")
```

**Issued Mail**

```
class IssuedMail(audit.MailModel):
    _name = 'issued.mail'
    _inherits = {'general.mail.adm': 'mail_id'}

    name = fields.Char(string="Number Mail",
                       help="contient code courr", readonly=True,
                       requred=True, index=True)

    receivers = fields.Char(string="The Receivers", required=True,
                            help="contains name of mail receivers")
    sending_date = fields.Date(string="Sending Date",
                               help="contains Sending Date of issued mail")
    mail_subject = fields.Char(string="Mail Subject",
                               help="contains the subject of messaging")
    doc_ref = fields.Char(string="Document Reference",
                          help="contains reference doc")
    doc_date = fields.Date(string="Document Date",
                           help="contains date of Document")
```

and **`General Mail`** must like this

```
class MailAdm(audit.JusticeModel):
    _name = 'general.mail.adm'
    _description = 'contient le courrier'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

    # num_courr
    #

    name = fields.Char(string="Serial Number",
                       help="contient code courr", readonly=True,
                       requred=True, index=True,)

    senders_receivers = fields.Char(string="Senders/Receivers", required=True,
                          help="contains name of mail senders")

    reception_send_date = fields.Date(string="Reception/Send Date",
                            help="contains date arrival of incoming mail")

    mail_subject = fields.Char(string="Mail Subject",
                               help="contains the subject of messaging")
    doc_ref = fields.Char(string="Document Reference",
                          help="contains Reference doc")
    doc_date = fields.Date(string="Document Date",
                           help="contains date of Document")
```

**the results like this :**

***Incoming mail***
[incoming mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMtym.png)

***Issued mail***

[issued mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOvdE.png)

***general mail*** 
[displaying the rows but without data !!!][3]

[when i select any row it show me like this ][4]

Any idea ! Anyone can help me a bit, please?

Comment: you have duplicated the fields you should not create the field that are shared between the two model.